# How to replace only characters located between numbers and leave unchanged those with different locations

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub, stringi

How to replace "." that is located within numbers with ",", but not replace "." located elsewhere?

Input data:

```
x_input="23.344,) abcd, 12899.2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
```

Expected ouput:

```
x_output
"23,344,) abcd, 12899,2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
```

I tried:

```
x_input<-"23.344,) abcd, 12899.2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
x_output<-gsub(".", ",", x_input))))
```

But this does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x_input="23.344,) abcd, 12899.2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."

x_input %>% 
  str_replace_all("(?<=\\d)\\.(?=\\d)", ",")

#> [1] "23,344,) abcd, 12899,2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
```

---

Or, in `base R`,

```r
gsub("(?<=\\d)\\.(?=\\d)", ",", x_input, perl = T)

#> [1] "23,344,) abcd, 12899,2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace a digit, dot and digit with the first digit, a comma and the second digit.

(Alternately use the pattern

```
r"{(\d)\.(\d?)}"
```

if it is sufficient to have a digit before the dot but not after the dot.)

No packages are used.

```
gsub(r"{(\d)\.(\d)}", r"{\1,\2}", x_input)
## [1] "23,344,) abcd, 12899,2, (,  efg; abef. gfdc."
```